# Slow Ubuntu Boot TIme

Tags: 20.10, boot-time

For some reason, my boot process is taking too long (almost 2.5 min.).

```
shivansh@devlab:~$ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 33.431s (firmware) + 8.979s (loader) + 3.920s (kernel) + 1min 39.559s (userspace) = 2min 25.890s 
graphical.target reached after 21.967s in userspace
```

How can I troubleshoot this and make my boot faster?

Here is the output of `systemd-analyze blame

```bsh
shivansh@devlab:~$ systemd-analyze blame
8.688s udisks2.service                                      
7.353s accounts-daemon.service                              
5.798s NetworkManager.service                               
5.726s polkit.service                                       
4.502s avahi-daemon.service                                 
4.462s switcheroo-control.service                           
4.458s thermald.service                                     
4.457s wpa_supplicant.service                               
4.457s systemd-logind.service                               
4.251s dev-sda2.device                                      
3.943s grub-common.service                                  
3.869s gpu-manager.service                                  
3.600s secureboot-db.service                                
3.600s ModemManager.service                                 
3.379s gdm.service                                          
3.112s preload.service                                      
2.635s systemd-resolved.service                             
2.366s rsyslog.service                                      
2.069s apport.service                                       
2.063s lm-sensors.service                                   
1.876s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
1.532s apparmor.service                                     
1.092s pppd-dns.service                                     
1.063s systemd-modules-load.service                         
 959ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
 861ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
 708ms swapfile.swap                                        
 672ms systemd-journald.service                             
 587ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
 586ms systemd-random-seed.service                          
 584ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1801\x2d413B.service
 582ms setvtrgb.service                                     
 521ms upower.service                                       
 476ms packagekit.service                                   
 475ms e2scrub_reap.service                                 
 414ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
 385ms systemd-udevd.service                                
 347ms keyboard-setup.service                               
 342ms kerneloops.service                                   
 338ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
 301ms openvpn.service                                      
 298ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
 291ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
 283ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
 279ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
 266ms update-notifier-download.service                     
 242ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
 240ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
 237ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
 236ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
 234ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
 227ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
 225ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
 215ms ufw.service                                          
 161ms colord.service                                       
 161ms user@1000.service                                    
 126ms apport-autoreport.service                            
 115ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
  92ms boot-efi.mount                                       
  73ms systemd-journal-flush.service                        
  66ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
  51ms console-setup.service                                
  21ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
  10ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
  10ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
   8ms alsa-restore.service                                 
   4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
   3ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
   2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

Neofetch Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiHJt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ModemManager

> ModemManager is a DBus-activated daemon which controls mobile
> broadband (2G/3G/4G) devices and connections. Whether built-in
> devices, USB dongles, Bluetooth-paired telephones or professional
> RS232/USB devices with external power supplies, ModemManager is able
> to prepare and configure the modems and setup connections with them.

If you don't use that type of hardware, you can disable the service.

`systemctl disable ModemManager`

### wpasupplicant

> client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)

With your hardware ("Lenovo ideapad") I assume that you want to use Wi-Fi. But if you don't need it everytime you boot your device, then you can disable this service.

`systemctl disable wpa_supplicant`

### apport

> automatic crash report generation

apport is useful, especially since you are using a new release of Ubuntu. But technically you don't need it, so you can disable this service.

`systemctl disable apport`

### thermald

> The thermald daemon prevents machines from overheating and was
> introduced in the 14.04 Ubuntu Trusty LTS release. It monitors thermal
> sensors and will modify cooling controls to keep the hardware cool.
> Thermald uses the available CPU temperature sensors and will keep the
> CPU from overheating.

On a desktop PC I would say you probably don't need this. I am not so sure about your mobile device. If you are absolutely not worried about overheating, then you can disable this service.

If you disable it and you don't have any other software running that is processing the sensor information (temperature/voltage/fan sensors), the `lm-sensors` service can be disabled too.

### switcheroo-control

> switcheroo-control is a D-Bus proxy for dual-GPU desktop integration.

I don't know exactly what this means. Maybe if you have two graphics devices installed, one onboard and one via extension card. From what I assume and what I see at Wikipedia, your Lenovo IdeaPad does not have more than one GPU. I would disable this service.

`systemctl disable switcheroo-control.service`

Comment: Thankyou! WIll have a look into your suggestion.

Comment: @Shivansh-007 I just added "switcheroo-control" to the answer. This would be another 4 seconds.

Comment: Not sure if I should disable that or not. Will look into it! Thanks @Sheldon